# AWS MSSQL RDS Instance periodically timing out

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Every 5 or so days (including just now) I get a barrage of timeout errors from my webapp.

If I look at what my SQL instance is doing in CloudWatch, it reports this:

Freeable space: http://cl.ly/NBRM

DB Connections: http://cl.ly/NBLH

Write throughput: http://cl.ly/NBFs

Read IOPS: http://cl.ly/NBp3

Write IOPS: http://cl.ly/NAre

Queue: http://cl.ly/NBA7

What the heck is happening? I don't believe its traffic related.
How do I find out what happened?

**Update: ** incremental backups are taken every 5 mins, and daily backups are done at 4am (i.e. not when this happens)

Thanks

Comment: It being in the cloud and whatnot, do you have visibility to movement of the guest from one host to another? Also how regular are your service interruptions? You say "about 5 days", but how much does that vary, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a spike of activity, the disk queue is not good however this all depends on what storage you are using, if this is virtualised or from some sort of SAN due to a hosted infrastrcture you might be using, queue depths can be meaningless. Even then you could really do with something even if this is something as simple as running sp_WhoIsAtive to see what sessions are active/suspended and what they are doing/what they are waiting on. There is not enough information to make any prognosis from, also the spike in I/O should not cause a half decent I/O sub system any issues.

Comment: It's AWS RDS, of course it's "virtualized or from some sort of SAN".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cloud resources will timeout for other reasons.
Amazon uses a ... policer ... for lack of some better term to help enforce their policies regarding utilization. When those limits are exceeded, they rarely tell you diddly squat, unless you happen to pay for premium support. They just throttle you and let you spin your wheels on what's going on.

!!!THOR!!!

What RDS instance size are you using for your MSSQL database? Smaller instances, especially those often in the free-tier (even if you're paying for it) will throttle you when you inevitably exceed it's resource utilization limits. Try to keep a CPU busy 100% of the time, and load it down with I/O ... it will crap out on you! Similarly, they have several other limits on the platform. How many instances you can launch in a region of a specific size, how much storage you can provision ... blah, blah, blah. You can pop a support ticket and often get those limits increased, even without paying for support. However, paid support requests get done a whole lot faster.

There are also some AWS regions that are more infamous for having problems. Try moving to a different service Availability Zone in-region. It helps to stop instances and start them again (totally different from restart!). A proper stop and start re-seats your instance on newer hardware or hardware that just underwent a maintenance activity. So fewer weird problems when the underlying hardware craps itself and your instance restarts without warning.

This stuff isn't isolated to AWS. All the major public clouds eventually have issues. Some will admit it. Others just say, check the status-page for more information but rarely pony up the real nitty gritty behind the root cause of an issue. Especially if it's limited in scope to only a few customers.

You're renting someone else's computer in someone totally different's data centers! What do you expect?!

The folks who do a really really good at utilizing public cloud resources, know that it's flaky as hell and plan for this. Read up on how Netflix uses AWS and goes so far as to let software start killing things willy nilly, to make sure that never impacts their ability to deliver videos to customers. It's actually really neato stuff!